# Xamarin Android Images not displaying

Tags: image, xaml, xamarin.android

Im trying to display an image on a kindle fire device using a Xamarin project.
The kindle device is android API level 15.

Ive tried to display the image using both URI and local resource techniques but both being used by XAML rather then code behind.

XAML code behind:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AbsoluteLayoutExercise.Exercise2">
  <StackLayout>
    <Image Source="Lily2.png" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

With PNG image (saved using MSPaint to make sure that it is an actual PNG) saved into resources/Drawable on the Android project.

XAML uri

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AbsoluteLayoutExercise.Exercise2">
  <StackLayout>
<Image Source="http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/nature/7" Aspect="AspectFill" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Both these ways build successfully but when deployed to the device in question, i get nothing but a white screen.

Anyone got any words of advice?

Comment: Did you try on any other devices? The picture showed up just fine when I tried to reproduce the issue with the exact same code using an Emulator which runs API 22.